# Unable to share C drive on Docker for Windows

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am running **Docker Desktop for Windows** on Windows 10 Enterprise.  I get the following:

> PS C:\Users> docker run --rm -v c:/Users:/data alpine ls /data
>   C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error
>   response from  daemon: C: drive is not share it in Docker for Windows
>   Settings.

From Docker settings in the Shared Drives tab, I see that the `C` drive is there, but it is not checked.  When I check it and press Apply, I am prompted for my password.  Upon entering it successfully, the `C` drive is still not checked.

Comment: is this issue resolved ?

Comment: I had the same issue, I wasn't able to resolve it and I ended up installing virtual box with ubuntu to run the project there...

Comment: @sp2danny, do you have special characters in your password? Non-english or any spaces? Also in the username. Are you using active directory? Also check if file sharing is enabled? https://cdn-enterprise.discourse.org/docker/uploads/default/optimized/2X/b/b10551d7301e2de3dd813d11b07e53010f5e50ea_1_690x372.png

Comment: @TarunLalwani : I do have special characters in my username. "ö" to be precise. should that make a difference?

Comment: @sp2danny Yes. Please change your password and use plain English text and it should work

Comment: @TarunLalwani : It worked, please write that as an answer

Comment: I had no special non English characters in my password. I currently use Docker on Ubuntu running on Virtual Box.

Comment: Docker edge Desktop Community 2.1.7.0  does not ask for password anymore

Answer (score 5):

There are different problems that people face with sharing. But the common one is a non-english character based password or a password with spaces.

If you can change your password and remove spaces/special non-english characters then it should work.

Other workaround that you can try is create a local user and give it access to C: and then when sharing C:\ in docker settings, using this local user credentials

Comment: Also, you have to use a local account and not your Microsoft account: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56375425/693737

Comment: Docker edge Desktop Community 2.1.7.0  does not ask for password anymore

Answer (score 0):

The user account supplied also needs to have admin permission. Seems obvious but Docker doesn't return an error message when it fails (Version 18.06.1-ce-win73 (19507)). Remember to subsequently run PowerShell as that admin account in order to access share.