# docker for windows, cannot share drive

Tags: windows, docker

```
docker:   Version 18.04.0-ce-rc2-win61 
windows 10 enterprise
```

I click settings in docker, click on shared drives, select any drive C, D, Z, etc.

Seems like it's about to share, then the drive check boxes un-check.

The logs contain the following:

```
[21:12:39.990][SharedDrivesSettings][Info   ] Apply shared drive settings<br>
[21:12:39.992][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Sending Version()...<br>
[21:12:39.994][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Received response for Version<br>
[21:12:39.994][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Sending Unmount(All, C, Docker.Core.Settings)...<br>
[21:12:39.994][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Version()<br>
[21:12:39.994][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Version done in 00:00:00.<br>
[21:12:39.996][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Unmount(All, C, Docker.Core.Settings)<br>
[21:12:39.996][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Unmount C<br>
[21:12:42.185][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Received response for Unmount<br>
[21:12:42.184][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Unmount done in 00:00:02.1885041.<br>
[21:12:42.201][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Sending Version()...<br>
[21:12:42.202][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Received response for Version<br>
[21:12:42.202][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Sending Mount(All, Z, NW\ws743e:**********, Docker.Core.Settings)...<br>
[21:12:42.202][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Version()<br>
[21:12:42.202][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Version done in 00:00:00.<br>
[21:12:42.204][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Mount(All, Z, NW\ws743e1234:**********, Docker.Core.Settings)<br>
[21:12:42.543][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Mount Z<br>
[21:12:43.260][Cmd            ][Info   ] This shared resource does not exist.<br>
[21:12:43.260][Cmd            ][Info   ] More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2310.<br>
[21:12:43.270][SambaShare     ][Info   ] "Z" is not shared<br>
[21:12:43.270][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Creating share "Z:\" as "Z" with Full Control to "NW\ws743e1234"<br>
[21:12:44.003][Cmd            ][Info   ] Z was shared successfully.<br>
[21:12:44.613][Cmd            ][Info   ] Share name        Z<br>
[21:12:44.613][Cmd            ][Info   ] Path              Z:\<br>
[21:12:44.613][Cmd            ][Info   ] Remark            <br>
[21:12:44.613][Cmd            ][Info   ] Maximum users     No limit<br>
[21:12:44.614][Cmd            ][Info   ] Users         <br>    
[21:12:44.614][Cmd            ][Info   ] Caching           Caching disabled<br>
[21:12:44.614][Cmd            ][Info   ] Permission        NW\ws743e1234, FULL<br>
[21:12:44.614][Cmd            ][Info   ] The command completed successfully.<br>
[21:12:44.626][SambaShare     ][Info   ] "Z" is shared<br>
[21:12:44.998][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Username: ws743e1234<br>
[21:12:44.998][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Host IP: 10.0.75.1<br>
[21:12:44.998][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Cifs options: noperm,iocharset=utf8,nobrl,mfsymlinks,vers=3.02,domain=NW,sec=ntlmsspi<br>
[21:12:46.700][SambaShare     ][Error  ] Unable to mount Z drive: C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.37/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.<br>

[21:12:46.700][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Removing share Z<br>
[21:12:47.468][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Mount Z<br>
[21:12:48.078][Cmd            ][Info   ] This shared resource does not exist.<br>
[21:12:48.078][Cmd            ][Info   ] More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2310.<br>
[21:12:48.095][SambaShare     ][Info   ] "Z" is not shared<br>
[21:12:48.095][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Creating share "Z:\" as "Z" with Full Control to "ws743e1234"<br>
[21:12:48.777][Cmd            ][Info   ] Z was shared successfully.<br>
[21:12:49.408][Cmd            ][Info   ] Share name        Z<br>
[21:12:49.408][Cmd            ][Info   ] Path              Z:\<br>
[21:12:49.408][Cmd            ][Info   ] Remark            <br>
[21:12:49.411][Cmd            ][Info   ] Maximum users     No limit<b<br>r>
[21:12:49.411][Cmd            ][Info   ] Users             
[21:12:49.411][Cmd            ][Info   ] Caching           Caching disabled<br>
[21:12:49.411][Cmd            ][Info   ] Permission        NW\ws743e1234, FULL<br>
[21:12:49.411][Cmd            ][Info   ] The command completed successfully.<br>
[21:12:49.422][SambaShare     ][Info   ] "Z" is shared<br>
[21:12:49.428][SambaShare     ][Error  ] Unable to validate cred: Invalid username or password<br>
[21:12:49.428][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Removing share Z<br>
[21:12:49.960][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Received response for Mount<br>
[21:12:49.960][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Mount done in 00:00:07.7555290.<br>
[21:13:05.778][CredentialAsker][Info   ] Storing credentials: NW\ws743e1234:***********<br>
[21:13:05.829][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Sending Version()...<br>
[21:13:05.831][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Received response for Version<br>
[21:13:05.831][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Sending Mount(All, Z, NW\ws743e1234:**********, Docker.Core.Settings)...<br>
[21:13:05.831][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Version()<br>
[21:13:05.831][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Version done in 00:00:00.<br>
[21:13:05.833][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Mount(All, Z, NW\ws743e1234:**********, Docker.Core.Settings)<br>
[21:13:06.056][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Mount Z<br>
[21:13:06.799][Cmd            ][Info   ] This shared resource does not exist.<br>
[21:13:06.800][Cmd            ][Info   ] More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2310.<br>
[21:13:06.811][SambaShare     ][Info   ] "Z" is not shared<br>
[21:13:06.811][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Creating share "Z:\" as "Z" with Full Control to "NW\ws743e1234"<br>
[21:13:07.438][Cmd            ][Info   ] Z was shared successfully.<br>
[21:13:08.009][Cmd            ][Info   ] Share name        Z<br>
[21:13:08.009][Cmd            ][Info   ] Path              Z:\<br>
[21:13:08.009][Cmd            ][Info   ] Remark            <br>
[21:13:08.009][Cmd            ][Info   ] Maximum users     No limit<br>
[21:13:08.009][Cmd            ][Info   ] Users             <br>
[21:13:08.009][Cmd            ][Info   ] Caching           Caching disabled<br>
[21:13:08.010][Cmd            ][Info   ] Permission        NW\ws743e1234, FULL
[21:13:08.010][Cmd            ][Info   ] The command completed successfully.<br>
[21:13:08.023][SambaShare     ][Info   ] "Z" is shared<br>
[21:13:08.117][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Username: ws743e1234<br>
[21:13:08.117][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Host IP: 10.0.75.1<br>
[21:13:08.117][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Cifs options: noperm,iocharset=utf8,nobrl,mfsymlinks,vers=3.02,domain=NW,sec=ntlmsspi
[21:13:10.052][SambaShare     ][Error  ] Unable to mount Z drive: C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: error during connect: Post http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.37/containers/create: open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker daemon is not running.
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.<br>

[21:13:10.052][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Removing share Z<br><br>
[21:13:10.957][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Mount Z<br>
[21:13:11.632][Cmd            ][Info   ] This shared resource does not exist.<br>
[21:13:11.632][Cmd            ][Info   ] More help is available by typing NET HELPMSG 2310.<br>
[21:13:11.647][SambaShare     ][Info   ] "Z" is not shared<br>
[21:13:11.647][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Creating share "Z:\" as "Z" with Full Control to "ws743e1234"<br>
[21:13:12.306][Cmd            ][Info   ] Z was shared successfully.<br>
[21:13:12.978][Cmd            ][Info   ] Share name        Z<br>
[21:13:12.978][Cmd            ][Info   ] Path              Z:\<br>
[21:13:12.978][Cmd            ][Info   ] Remark            <br>
[21:13:12.978][Cmd            ][Info   ] Maximum users     No limit<br>
[21:13:12.978][Cmd            ][Info   ] Users             <br>
[21:13:12.978][Cmd            ][Info   ] Caching           Caching disabled<br>
[21:13:12.979][Cmd            ][Info   ] Permission        NW\ws743e1234, FULL<br>
[21:13:12.979][Cmd            ][Info   ] The command completed successfully.<br>
[21:13:12.992][SambaShare     ][Info   ] "Z" is shared<br>
[21:13:12.998][SambaShare     ][Error  ] Unable to validate cred: Invalid username or password<br>
[21:13:12.998][SambaShare     ][Info   ] Removing share Z<br>
[21:13:13.629][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Received response for Mount<br>
[21:13:13.629][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Mount done in 00:00:07.7959981.<br>
[21:13:13.656][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Sending Version()...<br>
[21:13:13.657][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Received response for Version<br>
[21:13:13.657][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Sending GetDefaultVhdxPath()...<br>
[21:13:13.657][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Version()<br>
[21:13:13.659][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Received response for GetDefaultVhdxPath<br>
[21:13:13.657][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Version done in 00:00:00.<br>
[21:13:13.658][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] GetDefaultVhdxPath()<br>
[21:13:13.670][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Sending Version()...<br>
[21:13:13.734][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Received response for Version<br>
[21:13:13.734][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Sending TryGetVhdxSize(C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx)...<br>
[21:13:13.659][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] GetDefaultVhdxPath done in 00:00:00.0010018.<br>
[21:13:13.734][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Version()<br>
[21:13:13.734][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Version done in 00:00:00.<br>
[21:13:13.735][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] TryGetVhdxSize(C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx)<br>
[21:13:13.735][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script...<br>
[21:13:13.874][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Received response for TryGetVhdxSize<br>
[21:13:13.873][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] TryGetVhdxSize done in 00:00:00.1379989.<br>
[21:13:13.876][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Sending Version()...<br>
[21:13:13.877][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Received response for Version<br>
[21:13:13.877][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Sending TryGetVhdxSize(C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx)...<br>
[21:13:13.877][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Version()<br>
[21:13:13.877][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] Version done in 00:00:00.<br>
[21:13:13.878][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] TryGetVhdxSize(C:\Users\Public\Documents\Hyper-V\Virtual Hard Disks\MobyLinuxVM.vhdx)<br>
[21:13:13.878][PowerShell     ][Info   ] Run script...<br>
[21:13:13.977][NamedPipeClient][Info   ] Received response for TryGetVhdxSize<br>
[21:13:13.977][NamedPipeServer][Info   ] TryGetVhdxSize done in 00:00:00.0984980.<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently followed by [docker/for-win issue 1286](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1286):

> I have a similar issue from time to time with Docker for Windows somehow losing the ability to mount host volumes into containers.
>   This occurs on both Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016, most recently on Server 2016 with 17.09.0-ce-win33.
>
> The workaround that works for me is to restart the Docker daemon, although rarely a full system reboot will be required.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that sticks out in you log file is:

[21:13:12.998][SambaShare     ][Error  ] Unable to validate cred: Invalid username or password

Do you have any special characters in your password (besides a-Z 0-9)?
(Try choosing a password without special characters)

Otherwise, try click "reset credentials" and try again and make sure password has not expired.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was logged in with my Microsoft Account. Seems that Docker doesn't like that. I had to reconfigure my user to login with a local account and then it worked just fine.

You can do that by :

- Open the Windows menu
- Type "Your info"
- Click the "Sign in with a local account" link
- Set a password
- Sign-out
- Sign-in
- Do the Shared Drive thing in Docker

Also make sure your user is in the docker-users group from the Control Panel, Users management.